# Why am I getting the a "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type" error?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

Under `spark-shell`, after some computing, I got a value with type `HashMap`, but I can not list all `(key, value)`:

```
scala> provinces_cookies
res44: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int]] = MapPartitionsRDD[20] at map at <console>:44

scala> for( (k, v) <- provinces_cookies) println ( k + "-->" + v)
<console>:47: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2) 
required: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int]
          for( (k, v) <- provinces_cookies) println ( k + "-->" + v)
```

For listing all `key --> value`, what should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

provinces_cookies is RDD containing map so you should first iterate over RDD and then over Map:

```
 provinces_cookies.foreach ( hmap =>
    for((k,v) <- hmap) println (k + "-->" + v)
 )
```